# Server side excel export with DataTable

Tags: javascript, java, datatables

I have a DataTables with server side processing.
On server side I have functions retrieving filters from the ajax request and fetching data from database.

Now I want export data into excel file with filters.

I assume I have to design an excel file creator on server side and send the file through HTTP response.

I would like use already-defined functions to handle export request.

My question is: how can I send DataTables filter as same format as in the ajax request to my server ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You can use [`ajax.params()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.params%28%29) to get the data submitted by DataTables to the server in the last Ajax request.

Then you can redirect to script that generates Excel file with these parameters using jQuery helper function [`$.param`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) that converts array into query string.

For example:

```
window.location = '/getFile.php?' + $.param($('#example').DataTable().ajax.params());
```

where `example` is table ID.

> **NOTES**

There is also TableTools extension with [Download button](http://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/plug-ins#download) but with recent jQuery DataTables 1.10.8 release, TableTools extension is now deprecated.

Comment: @davidkonrad, the link is in the answer, the warning is shown on that page at the top.

Comment: @davidkonrad, yes, with 1.10.8 release. See [TableTools](http://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/) page: *New projects should use Buttons and Select in preference to TableTools.* I somewhat complained about documentation removal [here](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/79092/#Comment_79092) but I see where Allan goes with it.

Comment: Thank you So much, I am producing my own Excel reports server side and was struggling like mad to get values from ajax.params() this works a treat.