# DataTables - CSV Only Exports Current Rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have the following code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').DataTable( {
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": "/functions/ajax.asp",
                "ordering": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "dom": "<'row' <'col-md-12'B>><'row'<'col-md-6 col-sm-12'l><'col-md-6 col-sm-12'f>r><'table-scrollable't><'row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'p>>", // horizobtal scrollable datatable
                buttons: [
                'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
            ]
                } );
        } );
            </script>
```

I have around hundreds of rows but when I select the an option such as CSV, it only exports what is on the screen.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to export ajax/serverside datatable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067826/best-way-to-export-ajax-serverside-datatable)

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is that you're using server-side processing, so the client-side dataTables plugin only has access to the data on the screen to export! You'll have to make something custom to get this data from the server.

Check out this post for a quick example: [Server side excel export with DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32013725/server-side-excel-export-with-datatable)

Answer (score -1):

That is expected behavior for the export buttons in DataTables. They always simply export the data that is currently displayed on the screen. If you want to allow the user to export all data (and don't want to write a custom export function - if you do, see @Adam's answer), consider adding a `lengthMenu` option to your DataTable. This will allow users to change the number of records displayed per page, which can in turn let them show/export all records. The syntax for the `lengthMenu` parameter is as follows.

```
"lengthMenu": [ [10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"] ]
```

The first array shows the number of records to display for each option (in this case, 10, 25, 50, and all (-1 is all)), and the second array is what should be displayed in the user's dropdown menu.

See [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067826/best-way-to-export-ajax-serverside-datatable/38080001#38080001) for more detail on the topic.